# Есть ли терминал в линукс с кнопками?

Tags: linux, консоль

Мне нужен терминал, в котором я бы имел где-нибудь сбоку кнопки, нажав на которые выполнялась бы команда.
Например кнопка под консолью "Показать файлы", по нажатию на которую выполнялась бы команда ls.
В гугле найти что-то подобное не получилось, только в редакторе Атом находил пакет с такой функцией.
Может вы знаете уже готовое решение?

Linux: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: imho все подобные проекты провалились из-за полной невостребованности. Попробуйте [mc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander)

Comment: Написать команду быстрее, чем перекладывать руки с клавиатуры на мышь и обратно. Для более длинных команд используют алиасы и shell-скрипты.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, ну скорее уж completion — намного удобнее чем кастомизированные алиасы. а) Работает на любой системе, а не только на вашей, б) не нужно свою память перегружать избыточной информацией.

Comment: ТС: Глупости это всё. Я отказался несколько лет назад от `mc` в принципе, и как-то вот ничего не потерял.

Answer (score -1):

Я использую `Midnight Commander`, удобнее просматривать директории

### Как установить Midnight Commander в Linux

По умолчанию MC, как правило, не устанавливается. В Debian, Ubuntu и Linux Mint вы можете установить его с помощью команды apt-get:

`sudo apt-get install mc`

В RHEL, CentOS и Fedora вы можете использовать команду:

`yum install mc`

После завершения инсталляции просто введите `mc` в консоли для его запуска.

Comment: vifm наше все. даже можно алиас сделать на mc, что бы запускать было легче.